# A series question

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\sum_n a_n<\infty$ be a convergent series with positive entries. Is it true that the series
$$
\sum_n \frac{a_n}{a_n+a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}+\dots} 
$$
diverges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is (and is well-known). For any $n$, starting from $n$-th term, the sum of your series is at least 1: 
$$
\sum_{k\geqslant n} \frac{a_k}{a_k+a_{k+1}+\ldots}\geqslant 
\sum_{k\geqslant n} \frac{a_k}{a_n+a_{n+1}+\ldots}=1.
$$

This is not possible for a convergent series.

Comment: Indeed - many thanks!

Comment: It's impossible for a convergent series to sum to at least 1? I'm not sure what your answer is saying.

Comment: It is not possible that any tail of a convergent series sums to at least 1.

Comment: Sure, but if we take the sum $S=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n})$ yields the harmonic sum starting at 2 here. But your answer doesn't exactly explain why the harmonic series diverges...

Comment: I don't get your argument with the bounding. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: @SeanNemetz You probably mean $\sum (\frac1{n-1}-\frac1n)$. But why it does not? I think it does.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Alright, your proof makes sense now. Sorry for the hassle.